# What does this mean about a girl's action with her hair ? 髪を耳にかけている

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

I don't understand this expression, so much thanks if anyone can explain to me its meaning.

**髪を耳にかけている** (my guess is that she's adjusting (?) her hair behind her ear, but I'm not sure. And she's got a short hairstyle - its length is equal with her shoulders.)

Comment: Means something like this https://beauty.hotpepper.jp/slnH000405353/style/L134181158.html?cstt=7

Answer (score 2):

It's about having hair tucked behind the ears. It's more likely to describe the hair style, not the movement. The action of tucking is more commonly described as 髪を耳にかける.

Not to be confused with 髪が耳にかかる which is normally about hair strands partially hiding the ears.